# Pass parameter from non-react jquery html form page to react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactJS. 
I have a simple react app that runs fine independently.

Now I am calling it from exising HTML page and want to pass a parameter to react app and use that parameter inside react app.

I googled and found that window environment variable can be set and can be picked in the react app.

How do I do that? Any thoughts or samples, please?

Thanks!

```
Here is my scenario,

<html>
...
<body>
...
<a href="http://server.com/reactapp/index.html">call react app</a>
<input type="hidden" id="empno" value="1000" />
....
</body>
</html>
----
React app
index.js
--------------
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

let eno = document.getElementById("empno");

ReactDOM.render(<Products empnumber={eno}/>, document.getElementById('root'));


app.js
------
...
 render() {
        console.log(this.props.empnumber);

console log displays null. Thanks!
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to give you a helpful answer

Comment: Hi  stackoverfloweth, updated above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this article](https://github.com/danburzo/react-recipes/blob/master/recipes/inserting-components.md#updating-the-component) useful:

> The way our React component receives data from the outside world is via its props. Whenever we need to update the component with new data — and this is the part that feels magic in its simplicity — we just render it again using the new props, and React knows how to do it efficiently.

In a nutshell, find the part that calls `ReactDOM.render(<App/>, container)` or similar, and pass your value as a property to `App`, such as `<App someprop={somevalue}/>`

Comment: I tried what you said. it is returning null valiue.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass values to your React component when you're mounting it to the dom like so:

```
const someJson = {
    value1: '123',
    value2: '456',
};

render(<App someProp={someJson} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const querystring=window.location.search;
const urlParams=new URLSearchParams(querystring);
const empnumber=urlParams.get('empnumber');
```

You can then pass the variables as props to your component

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing your react app via a link as you described you could use query strings?

`<a href="http://server.com/reactapp/index.html?empnumber=1234">call react app</a>`

then in your component you can access the query string like this

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.location.query.empnumber);
}
```

there is also a nice [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to access query string from React component

Comment: I did what you said. I get this error Uncaught ... TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: I did what you said. I get this error Uncaught ... TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: Are you using `React-Router`?

Comment: Try a `console.log(this.props)` and see if `empnumber` is in there somewhere

Comment: I do not use React-Router. console.log(this.props) does not have empnumber. I use react v 16.4

Comment: could you please respond?